# Get all the paragraphs of the current node programmatically in form_views_exposed_form_alter

Tags: views, 8, paragraphs

I have a content type with multiple field paragraph. I would like to get all the paragraphs from the current node in form_views_exposed_form_alter.

I tried

```
 $node = menu_get_object();
 $storage = Drupal::getContainer()->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('paragraph');
 $pids = $storage->getQuery();
```

which gets me all the paragraphs not only the ones of the current node. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the paragraphs are attached to your node via field. Let's assume the field is called `field_paragraphs`. Try the following:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$paragraphs = $node->get('field_paragraphs')->getValue();
```

This works because Drupal's routing system utilizes [upcasting](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/parameter-upcasting-in-routes) to promote the nid to a fully loaded node reference.